# Почему не показывает изображение?

Tags: java, android

Есть splashScrin на этом экране должно появляться изображение, но по какой то причине изображение показывается не на всех устройствах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код SplashActivity

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private PrefManager prefManager;
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        context = SplashActivity.this;

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
        }else{
            timeHandler();
        }
    }

    private void timeHandler(){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        //prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, IntroActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.heven.taxicabondemandtaxi.driver.activity.SplashActivity"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorLogo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLogoBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/votre_taxi_en_un_clic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: а на каких не видно картинку? версия оси желательно чтобы была известна, а то так сложно помочь

Comment: Smsung, xiaomi всё норм. На huawei не показывает

Comment: а у вас доступ к телефону есть которые не показывает?

Comment: нет а что, могу узнать

Comment: просто думал предложить через layout inspector посмотреть) можно конечно посмотреть хардкорно добавив фон виджету и пусть человек вам фото сделает как вариант

Comment: Как понять добавить фон?

Comment: например через xml -> background, то есть чтобы понять что виджет отрисовывается

Comment: Желтый цвет и есть background LinearLayout

Comment: нет, я имел ввиду фон для imageview а не для контейнера, или у вас картинка должна быть у linearlayout?

Comment: Выше скинул код xml

Comment: Где то читал что нужно наследование от extends AppCompatActivity на данный момент extends BaseActivity а уже у BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: можно во-первых уточнить версию андроида, во-вторых - попробовать на эмуляторе такой же версии, и наконец если совсем ничего не проявилось то установить фон у imageview скинуть человеку и если у него будет цветной квадрат то значит виджет отрисовывает и проблемы с доступом к картинке

Comment: Ок а если с доступом к картинке что тогда?

Comment: а вы распространяете это приложение как - маркет или напрямую?

Comment: на прямую скидываю apk на  samsung работает на huawei нет

Comment: Тогда попроще будет) измените наследование на AppCompatActivity и добавьте фон какой-то и скиньте, по логике с картинкой проблем быть не должно

Comment: Возможно проблема в открытие изображения android: src="" а должно быть app:srcCompat=""

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение своего вопроса. Я перепробовал по крайней мере ещё два варианта кода splash screen, но нечего не помогало. Решением оказалось изменение большего разрешение изображения на несколько раз меньше и формат jpg изменил на png.

Comment: а вы знаете про спецификации drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi и т.п.?

Comment: Нет не знаю, можно инфу по этому поводу?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities